# TYPO3: Wrap content elements with div

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have created multiple Text&Image elements on a page (TYPO3 9.5). What I would need now is, to wrap all these content elements with a div. What TYPO3 creates is:

```
<div>...content 1...</div>
<div>...content 2...</div>
<div>...content 3...</div>
```

What I need is an additional div containing all the TYPO3 created divs:

```
<div class="">
     <div>...content 1...</div>
     <div>...content 2...</div>
     <div>...content 3...</div>
</div>
```

I know I could reconstruct the code I want using the HTML-element, but it would be great to use TYPO3s content elements. My content structure is:

Text - Image - Text - Image - Text -Image

In Joomla's JCE-Editor, there is an opportunity to create one content element, containing this structure. But TYPO3's logic is way different there. Can anyone give me a hint, how to achive this goal?

I already managed to assign each page a unique id. Maybe there is a typoscript, how to use this div containing the specific ID to wrap it's content with another div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessful research to solve the problem using typoscript, I decided to create a new Mask Element using TYPO3's Mask Extension, which allows me to reach my goal.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your page templating there could be different options.

state of the art techniques include usage of fluid page templates where you can put a `<div>...</div>` around your content.

How does your page template get the content?

if you use fluid variables defined in typoscript you probably use `styles.content.get`. just put a wrap around it:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    :
    variables {
        :
        maincontent < styles.content.get
        maincontent.wrap = <div class="...">|</div>
    }
}
```